# Can't submit GitHub password

Tags: git, github, access-token

When I enter `git push` I'm prompted to enter my username and password for GitHub. I had no trouble inputting my username and I made a personal access token to substitute for my password, but the command line for my password won't let me enter or paste any text. The only thing I can do is hit enter which tells me that it wasn't able to access my GitHub and returned a 403 error. Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "the command line for my password won't let me enter or paste any text"? Are you aware that [there's no password feedback in the terminal on Unix-like systems](/q/112069/301745)?

Answer (score 2):

The password, even if you type it in, won't show up on the command line.
Just type it in - even if it doesn't appear - and hit Enter.

Comment: Is there a way to make it appear?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated command line doesn’t let you enter password only let you hit enter.

**By default Linux Command Lines doesn’t visualize passwords for security concerns. That might be the reason you can’t see any inputs.**

You can push commits without entering password every time.

`git remote set-url https://yourgitHubusername:youraccesstoken@github.com/yourgithubusername/reponame.git`

- Note: this will store your git credentials in plain text in gitconfig

To Add all changes `git add .`

To commit all changes `git commit -m "commit message"`

To push changes `git push origin main`